# ImageMagick not processing all PNG files when converting to PDF

Tags: imagemagick

I have a PDF file with some pages being incorrectly oriented.  I am trying to fix this and to do so, extracting all images as PNG (lossless), fix orientation and re-create a PDF.

To do this, I ran the pdfimages command:

```
pdfimages -png test.pdf foo
```

Which generated 240 or so of PNG files, named like foo-000.png and so on.  Everything seems good.

However, when I run:

```
convert -quality 100 *.png new.pdf
```

The resulting new.pdf file only contains 55 pages out of 240.  Could anyone advise why this might be?  I don't see any obvious errors on the screen and I don't quite understand why it doesn't process all PNG files, all sitting in the same directory and numbered in sequence.  Thank you.

Edit: Addressing comments from @fmw42:

```
foo-000.png PNG 811x1369 811x1369+0+0 8-bit sRGB 863037B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-001.png PNG 1660x2741 1660x2741+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 15779B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-002.png PNG 1662x2743 1662x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 32586B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-003.png PNG 1652x2743 1652x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 34658B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-004.png PNG 1660x2743 1660x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 16886B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-005.png PNG 1654x2735 1654x2735+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 57090B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-006.png PNG 1658x2745 1658x2745+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 4036B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-007.png PNG 1658x2743 1658x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 33787B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-008.png PNG 2740x1649 2740x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61294B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-009.png PNG 826x1372 826x1372+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 308314B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-010.png PNG 2742x1649 2742x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 58647B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-011.png PNG 1658x2745 1658x2745+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61920B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-012.png PNG 2740x1649 2740x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62151B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-013.png PNG 1650x2743 1650x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 57237B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-014.png PNG 2740x1649 2740x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 67751B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-015.png PNG 2742x1649 2742x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62368B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-016.png PNG 2738x1645 2738x1645+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 59511B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-017.png PNG 1646x2745 1646x2745+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63359B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-018.png PNG 2742x1645 2742x1645+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 65173B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-019.png PNG 1640x2745 1640x2745+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63532B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-020.png PNG 2740x1641 2740x1641+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62590B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-021.png PNG 1642x2745 1642x2745+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 70618B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-022.png PNG 1640x2737 1640x2737+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62976B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-023.png PNG 1642x2743 1642x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63677B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-024.png PNG 2740x1631 2740x1631+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63156B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-025.png PNG 819x1371 819x1371+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 280669B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-026.png PNG 2738x1631 2738x1631+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 60419B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-027.png PNG 2744x1659 2744x1659+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 64470B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-028.png PNG 2740x1655 2740x1655+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 56055B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-029.png PNG 2748x1653 2748x1653+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61986B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-030.png PNG 2744x1653 2744x1653+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62517B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-031.png PNG 2732x1659 2732x1659+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 60172B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-032.png PNG 2730x1655 2730x1655+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 65304B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-033.png PNG 828x1368 828x1368+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 308276B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-034.png PNG 2736x1657 2736x1657+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 55901B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-035.png PNG 2734x1659 2734x1659+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 64016B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-036.png PNG 2728x1653 2728x1653+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 66712B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-037.png PNG 1656x2731 1656x2731+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 29590B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-038.png PNG 1658x2727 1658x2727+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 35067B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-039.png PNG 2746x1659 2746x1659+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 66504B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-040.png PNG 2738x1651 2738x1651+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 66758B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-041.png PNG 2746x1657 2746x1657+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 59626B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-042.png PNG 1656x2739 1656x2739+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 57147B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-043.png PNG 2748x1655 2748x1655+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 65837B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-044.png PNG 1644x2739 1644x2739+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 68070B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-045.png PNG 2750x1649 2750x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 53961B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-046.png PNG 2742x1639 2742x1639+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 64328B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-047.png PNG 2748x1653 2748x1653+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 70157B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-048.png PNG 821x1373 821x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 632860B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-049.png PNG 826x1374 826x1374+0+0 8-bit sRGB 816354B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-050.png PNG 820x1373 820x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 851163B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-051.png PNG 1650x2747 1650x2747+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 59971B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-052.png PNG 820x1372 820x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 797013B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-053.png PNG 1652x2747 1652x2747+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 67124B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-054.png PNG 819x1373 819x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 812509B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-055.png PNG 826x1374 826x1374+0+0 8-bit sRGB 768898B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-056.png PNG 817x1372 817x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 645606B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-057.png PNG 1653x2748 1653x2748+0+0 8-bit sRGB 134735B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-058.png PNG 821x1371 821x1371+0+0 8-bit sRGB 764537B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-059.png PNG 824x1373 824x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 824632B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-060.png PNG 821x1370 821x1370+0+0 8-bit sRGB 650050B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-061.png PNG 823x1374 823x1374+0+0 8-bit sRGB 766561B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-062.png PNG 818x1370 818x1370+0+0 8-bit sRGB 716083B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-063.png PNG 830x1372 830x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 744148B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-064.png PNG 2742x1655 2742x1655+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 66396B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-065.png PNG 2742x1661 2742x1661+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 68816B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-066.png PNG 1656x2737 1656x2737+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 41455B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-067.png PNG 1660x2743 1660x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 32537B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-068.png PNG 2740x1657 2740x1657+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 64692B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-069.png PNG 1668x2745 1668x2745+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 68550B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-070.png PNG 2740x1655 2740x1655+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62729B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-071.png PNG 2742x1667 2742x1667+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 56160B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-072.png PNG 829x1371 829x1371+0+0 8-bit sRGB 797036B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-073.png PNG 834x1374 834x1374+0+0 8-bit sRGB 775010B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-074.png PNG 828x1370 828x1370+0+0 8-bit sRGB 851987B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-075.png PNG 2746x1665 2746x1665+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 58976B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-076.png PNG 2742x1655 2742x1655+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 69594B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-077.png PNG 833x1373 833x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 781652B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-078.png PNG 827x1372 827x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 662858B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-079.png PNG 831x1376 831x1376+0+0 8-bit sRGB 784349B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-080.png PNG 825x1372 825x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 862631B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-081.png PNG 832x1375 832x1375+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 299839B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-082.png PNG 823x1373 823x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 930388B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-083.png PNG 830x1372 830x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 713801B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-084.png PNG 2742x1647 2742x1647+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 66628B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-085.png PNG 828x1374 828x1374+0+0 8-bit sRGB 691227B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-086.png PNG 2740x1645 2740x1645+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61786B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-087.png PNG 827x1374 827x1374+0+0 8-bit sRGB 736898B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-088.png PNG 823x1370 823x1370+0+0 8-bit sRGB 737153B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-089.png PNG 2746x1653 2746x1653+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 60026B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-090.png PNG 2742x1645 2742x1645+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61806B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-091.png PNG 1656x2745 1656x2745+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 11639B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-092.png PNG 2744x1645 2744x1645+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 33051B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-093.png PNG 1656x2749 1656x2749+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63322B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-094.png PNG 822x1371 822x1371+0+0 8-bit sRGB 630895B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-095.png PNG 830x1372 830x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 781857B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-096.png PNG 2736x1641 2736x1641+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62180B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-097.png PNG 2744x1653 2744x1653+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61320B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-098.png PNG 2742x1641 2742x1641+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 55956B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-099.png PNG 826x1371 826x1371+0+0 8-bit sRGB 716384B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-100.png PNG 1642x2735 1642x2735+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 56603B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-101.png PNG 2738x1647 2738x1647+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61265B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-102.png PNG 2734x1637 2734x1637+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61491B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-103.png PNG 2742x1651 2742x1651+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 64134B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-104.png PNG 2736x1645 2736x1645+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63315B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-105.png PNG 2748x1651 2748x1651+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 58804B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-106.png PNG 2746x1641 2746x1641+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 54907B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-107.png PNG 2744x1649 2744x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 54446B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-108.png PNG 820x1370 820x1370+0+0 8-bit sRGB 699744B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-109.png PNG 2748x1651 2748x1651+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 56913B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-110.png PNG 2744x1639 2744x1639+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62408B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-111.png PNG 826x1373 826x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 705947B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-112.png PNG 2740x1643 2740x1643+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 54017B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-113.png PNG 2740x1645 2740x1645+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62005B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-114.png PNG 822x1372 822x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 626748B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-115.png PNG 824x1372 824x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 804754B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-116.png PNG 2740x1643 2740x1643+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 58537B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-117.png PNG 2744x1649 2744x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 60881B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-118.png PNG 2742x1641 2742x1641+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 66037B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-119.png PNG 1652x2741 1652x2741+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 22642B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-120.png PNG 817x1368 817x1368+0+0 8-bit sRGB 423405B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-121.png PNG 2744x1643 2744x1643+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 58476B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-122.png PNG 820x1369 820x1369+0+0 8-bit sRGB 799003B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-123.png PNG 2742x1647 2742x1647+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 59131B 0.000u 0:00.009
foo-124.png PNG 820x1368 820x1368+0+0 8-bit sRGB 811468B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-125.png PNG 820x1372 820x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 832165B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-126.png PNG 2738x1631 2738x1631+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 51623B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-127.png PNG 818x1372 818x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 760412B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-128.png PNG 814x1368 814x1368+0+0 8-bit sRGB 804751B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-129.png PNG 838x1374 838x1374+0+0 8-bit sRGB 725536B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-130.png PNG 833x1370 833x1370+0+0 8-bit sRGB 761275B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-131.png PNG 2746x1679 2746x1679+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61851B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-132.png PNG 2738x1667 2738x1667+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62108B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-133.png PNG 2746x1681 2746x1681+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 64475B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-134.png PNG 2742x1671 2742x1671+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 53838B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-135.png PNG 2740x1675 2740x1675+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 67007B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-136.png PNG 832x1368 832x1368+0+0 8-bit sRGB 778577B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-137.png PNG 2744x1675 2744x1675+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 55701B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-138.png PNG 832x1369 832x1369+0+0 8-bit sRGB 775769B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-139.png PNG 2744x1681 2744x1681+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62509B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-140.png PNG 1670x2741 1670x2741+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 64326B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-141.png PNG 2744x1679 2744x1679+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 59943B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-142.png PNG 835x1370 835x1370+0+0 8-bit sRGB 767414B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-143.png PNG 1684x2727 1684x2727+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63949B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-144.png PNG 2720x1673 2720x1673+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 65629B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-145.png PNG 1680x2729 1680x2729+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 66209B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-146.png PNG 2722x1669 2722x1669+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 65949B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-147.png PNG 1670x2733 1670x2733+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 55531B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-148.png PNG 832x1365 832x1365+0+0 8-bit sRGB 693593B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-149.png PNG 835x1369 835x1369+0+0 8-bit sRGB 736226B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-150.png PNG 2736x1663 2736x1663+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 56517B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-151.png PNG 834x1363 834x1363+0+0 8-bit sRGB 797981B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-152.png PNG 832x1363 832x1363+0+0 8-bit sRGB 746904B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-153.png PNG 837x1369 837x1369+0+0 8-bit sRGB 739076B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-154.png PNG 2730x1663 2730x1663+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 66874B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-155.png PNG 838x1368 838x1368+0+0 8-bit sRGB 789193B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-156.png PNG 834x1366 834x1366+0+0 8-bit sRGB 854017B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-157.png PNG 835x1369 835x1369+0+0 8-bit sRGB 113263B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-158.png PNG 1662x2733 1662x2733+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 34563B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-159.png PNG 833x1376 833x1376+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 365802B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-160.png PNG 831x1373 831x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 782775B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-161.png PNG 835x1375 835x1375+0+0 8-bit sRGB 783695B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-162.png PNG 2750x1663 2750x1663+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 65274B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-163.png PNG 832x1375 832x1375+0+0 8-bit sRGB 801005B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-164.png PNG 2744x1651 2744x1651+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 59873B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-165.png PNG 2746x1663 2746x1663+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 58454B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-166.png PNG 2746x1653 2746x1653+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63340B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-167.png PNG 2748x1663 2748x1663+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61988B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-168.png PNG 1656x2743 1656x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 67475B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-169.png PNG 2752x1665 2752x1665+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 58072B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-170.png PNG 2744x1659 2744x1659+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 58085B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-171.png PNG 834x1374 834x1374+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 301269B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-172.png PNG 2742x1661 2742x1661+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 51158B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-173.png PNG 2744x1667 2744x1667+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61434B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-174.png PNG 830x1370 830x1370+0+0 8-bit sRGB 792927B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-175.png PNG 834x1372 834x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 605049B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-176.png PNG 831x1370 831x1370+0+0 8-bit sRGB 736585B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-177.png PNG 833x1374 833x1374+0+0 8-bit sRGB 721604B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-178.png PNG 2740x1657 2740x1657+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61861B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-179.png PNG 828x1375 828x1375+0+0 8-bit sRGB 766558B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-180.png PNG 2746x1647 2746x1647+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 64992B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-181.png PNG 2746x1651 2746x1651+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 46493B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-182.png PNG 1646x2739 1646x2739+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 70466B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-183.png PNG 826x1371 826x1371+0+0 8-bit sRGB 804529B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-184.png PNG 822x1369 822x1369+0+0 8-bit sRGB 818013B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-185.png PNG 2756x1675 2756x1675+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 54018B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-186.png PNG 2740x1663 2740x1663+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 65342B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-187.png PNG 2748x1673 2748x1673+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 51015B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-188.png PNG 833x1373 833x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 733421B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-189.png PNG 837x1373 837x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 786749B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-190.png PNG 831x1373 831x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 519091B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-191.png PNG 1676x2745 1676x2745+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 35346B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-192.png PNG 1668x2739 1668x2739+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 57454B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-193.png PNG 839x1374 839x1374+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 299936B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-194.png PNG 2744x1669 2744x1669+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 56614B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-195.png PNG 2750x1671 2750x1671+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 56848B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-196.png PNG 2746x1667 2746x1667+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63438B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-197.png PNG 1674x2743 1674x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 64047B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-198.png PNG 2742x1673 2742x1673+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62506B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-199.png PNG 1670x2743 1670x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61062B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-200.png PNG 2738x1661 2738x1661+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 52721B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-201.png PNG 2752x1661 2752x1661+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63526B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-202.png PNG 1652x2745 1652x2745+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 58859B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-203.png PNG 2744x1659 2744x1659+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 55740B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-204.png PNG 2740x1653 2740x1653+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 52060B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-205.png PNG 2748x1661 2748x1661+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 65644B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-206.png PNG 2746x1649 2746x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 56020B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-207.png PNG 2750x1657 2750x1657+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 53848B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-208.png PNG 2744x1649 2744x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63891B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-209.png PNG 2752x1661 2752x1661+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 52842B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-210.png PNG 2746x1657 2746x1657+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 50461B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-211.png PNG 1654x2743 1654x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 69020B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-212.png PNG 1650x2739 1650x2739+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 61207B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-213.png PNG 2744x1655 2744x1655+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 48930B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-214.png PNG 2740x1649 2740x1649+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 57365B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-215.png PNG 2748x1659 2748x1659+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 65895B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-216.png PNG 1650x2739 1650x2739+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 65981B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-217.png PNG 828x1373 828x1373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 706122B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-218.png PNG 2736x1647 2736x1647+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 62707B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-219.png PNG 829x1372 829x1372+0+0 8-bit sRGB 766365B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-220.png PNG 2738x1651 2738x1651+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 56923B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-221.png PNG 830x1371 830x1371+0+0 8-bit sRGB 796760B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-222.png PNG 826x1368 826x1368+0+0 8-bit sRGB 781198B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-223.png PNG 812x1371 812x1371+0+0 8-bit sRGB 219483B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-224.png PNG 2740x1613 2740x1613+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 39022B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-225.png PNG 1628x2747 1628x2747+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 71429B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-226.png PNG 1620x2743 1620x2743+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 51757B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-227.png PNG 2750x1631 2750x1631+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 40692B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-228.png PNG 2740x1621 2740x1621+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 52903B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-229.png PNG 2746x1635 2746x1635+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 22393B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-230.png PNG 2742x1621 2742x1621+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 49420B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-231.png PNG 2742x1635 2742x1635+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 39622B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-232.png PNG 1638x2745 1638x2745+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 30549B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-233.png PNG 2738x1627 2738x1627+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 63849B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-234.png PNG 2744x1643 2744x1643+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 40637B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-235.png PNG 1636x2739 1636x2739+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 42418B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-236.png PNG 2744x1641 2744x1641+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 40148B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-237.png PNG 1638x2737 1638x2737+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 44867B 0.000u 0:00.000
foo-238.png PNG 1642x2741 1642x2741+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 11059B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I also ran convert with -debug and here is where it seems to go south:

```
$ convert -debug "Cache,Blob" *.png abc.pdf
# looks OK up to foo-056.png
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/WritePixelCachePixels/5979/Cache
  foo-056.png[0][817x1+0+1352]
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/ReadPixelCachePixels/4905/Cache
  foo-056.png[0][817x1+0+1365]
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/WritePixelCachePixels/5979/Cache
  foo-056.png[0][817x1+0+1365]
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/ReadPixelCachePixels/4905/Cache
  foo-056.png[0][817x1+0+1371]
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/WritePixelCachePixels/5979/Cache
  foo-056.png[0][817x1+0+1371]
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Blob convert-im6.q16[33220]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2766/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1182/Cache
  destroy 
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Blob convert-im6.q16[33220]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2766/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1182/Cache
  destroy 
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Blob convert-im6.q16[33220]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2766/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1182/Cache
  destroy foo-057.png[0]
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Blob convert-im6.q16[33220]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2766/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1182/Cache
  destroy 
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Blob convert-im6.q16[33220]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2766/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1182/Cache
  destroy 
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Blob convert-im6.q16[33220]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2766/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2020-08-26T09:35:38-07:00 0:02.610 4.630u 6.9.10 Cache convert-im6.q16[33220]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1182/Cache
  destroy foo-058.png[0]
```

What's interesting is, I also tried creating a PDF by deleting the first 60 images or so.  The new PDF grabbed 72 pages this time, once again creating a different incomplete PDF file.

Comment: Run `identify *.png` and see if it lists all png files. If not, then post one of the missing png files.

Comment: Are there duplicated names?

Comment: Thank you, I posted more output / logs.  No duplicate names.

Comment: Can you determine one file that is missing and post a link to it, if it opens in your file system?  What is your ImageMagick version and platform/OS?

Comment: Do you have enough RAM to hold all your input files. Your command will try to open and keep in memory all 240 files. It is possible you have enough memory to hold them, but then not enough memory to hold the output as well, which will be as large as all the input. So your write may fail at that point, which could be just 55 files. Also be sure your /tmp directory is not full with left-over failed files that did not get deleted.

Comment: I have 16GB of RAM, I don't have much open (just Chrome and this).  The PDF is around 10MB, each image size is around 100KB (varies wildly though).  With that said, I'll poke around ImageMagick side of settings in case they might be getting in the way.

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version and platform/OS?

Comment: If your PNG files are about 2000x3000 pixels then the uncompressed file size would be about 6 M pixels. IM 6 will need 4 channels even if gray so 24 MB each. IM 7 would only use one channel, so 6 MB.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and $ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220515/discussion-between-fmw42-and-marseille07).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:
Per @fmw42's suggestion, I bumped these settings in /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml to 2GiB then noticed that the resulting PDF contained more pages.  I kept on bumping the value until I see all the pages.

```
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="4GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="4GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16KP"/>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="list-length" value="128"/> -->
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="4GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="4GiB"/>
```

Comment: It was likely the memory.